# Can I update my map with another players map?

Tags: terraria

If I play multiplayer with a friend and we go into separate caves for example, will my map then update with what he sees as well?

Is there a way to make it do this?

Answer (score 1):

No you're map will only be updated with whatever you see.

There is no way to do what you want with un-modded Terraria. There may be mods which will do what you want but I'm unaware of any and it's unlikely that they exist.

Each person's map file is stored in `Documents/My Games/Terraria/Players/<name>`, with the name of the world as a `.map` file. So you could open up your friends map file if you wanted to.